# Create virtual serial port programmatically

Tags: java, c#, delphi

I want to create virtual serial port programmatically in c#,delphi or java and use this port for printer port. so this should created in ports(com & LPT) in device manager. but com0com create a new branch in device manager like "com0com - serial ports emulator" and does not display this port in printers ports list.how can i create virtual serial port programmatically that i can use this in printer ports.

Comment: As I understand, you would be satisfied if a com0com port appeared in the Windows device manager as a real COM port. In this case you should set up a com0com port with the "use Ports class" option, and give it a usual name as 'COMx' instead of CNCA0 etc.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you cant in any of the languages you tagged .

In essence, you will need to write a device driver (i believe Delphi had a port for the DDK at one stage). Although this is not impossible, given the very fact that you asked this question here i'm guessing its a little bit above your level and a steeper learning curve than you might anticipate.

However, there are plenty of com port emulators floating about if you need to test against something. Just search google.

Comment: For example [Virtual Serial Port Driver](https://www.eltima.com/products/vspdxp/) offers DLL or ActiveX API to control their driver, so technically yes, by just consuming that product :)